# how to explode a data coming from database with dash

Tags: php, mysql

how to explode data from database to separate them into array
for example BSIT-1
`$course=$row['course'];` which is the BSIT-1
`$word=$course;`
`$split=(explode("-", $word));`
`echo $split[0];`=BSIT
`echo $split[1];`=1 (not working)
this code only echo BSIT and does not show the second array

Comment: $word is string or array?

Comment: check var_dump($split); please post it here.

Comment: BSITarray(1) { [0]=> string(4) "BSIT" }

Comment: there is only one element in $split array. thats why $split[1] does not printing anything.  now just do echo $word and then $split=explode("-", $word); and var_dump($split);

Comment: check this: https://3v4l.org/RooSr

Comment: that works but it doest work if the string comes from the database

Comment: your string will not be "BSIT-1" when you are retrieving it from database, just echo your string after fetching it and just before your explode statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r(explode('-',$split));die;
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => BSIT
)

Comment: i need to get the 1 from BSIT-1

Comment: But I got the correct result.

Array
(
    [0] => BSIT
    [1] => 1
)

Comment: It would be great if you'd not only just drop some code, but also give an explanation of what is going on in his and your code. It helps the question author and other users. It's good if it works, but knowing why is even more important in my opinion.

Comment: See.... 
You have string BSIT-1
The explode function returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.